# How to pass the value to the Text field of Extension Window? (Firefox WebExtension)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to write my first WebExtension for Firefox 60.0.1 Quantum, and ask for your help.

I'm try to briefly describe my Firefox WebExtension.

- Step 1. In the browser panel, press the extention button, - opens my
  Extension Window.
- Step 2. In this Extention Window there is a HTML-Page (file
  window.html) with a text field called "Active Tab URL" (id="url").
- Step 3. When switching/updating Tabs in main browser window, this
  text field should contain URL of the Active/Opened Tab.

My Questions:

1. How can I pass (from background.js) a any value to the text field (id="url") of my Extension Window?
2. How can I get the URL of the active Tab, to transfer it to my Extension Window?

I searched the information on the site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions
but unfortunately I did not understand how it can be done.

Thank you for your help and ideas!

---

### **manifest.json**

```
{

  "description": "Adds browser action icon to toolbar to open packaged web page.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension Window",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "contextMenus", "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead"],
  "icons": {"48": "icons/icon-48.png"},

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-32.png"
  }

}
```

---

### **background.js**

```
function openMyWindow() {

    var createWindow = {
    type: "detached_panel",
    url: "window.html",
    titlePreface: "Extension Window",
    width: 350,
    height: 950
    };


    let windowId;

    browser.windows.create(createWindow).then((data) => {
    windowId = data.id;});    

/*
1. How can I pass a any value to the text field (id="url") of my Extension Window?
2. How can I get the URL of the active Tab, to transfer it to my Extension Window?
*/  


}


/*
Add openMyWindow() as a listener to clicks on the browser action.
*/
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openMyWindow);
```

---

### **window.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension Window</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>  

<h1>My Extention Window</h1>
<p>Active Tab URL: <input id="url" type="text"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, let's get to the solution.

In `background.js`, you keep the URL of the current (interesting) tab in memory. Since the extension window is also a tab, we filter that out in setUrlIfDesired. In onCreated we filter about:blank and about:newtab, since those two are used by Firefox to indicate that the tab has not finished loading yet.

As soon as the URL changes to something interesting, we use `sendMessageToBrowserPopup` to notify the extension screen that it needs updating.

```
// Keep URL changes in a variable
let urlOfCurrentTab = null;

// Keep the id of the created window
let windowId = -1;

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) => {
    if(changeInfo.url) {
        // Here anything is allowed, even about:blank and about:newtab
        setUrlIfDesired("updated", changeInfo.url, tabInfo.active);
    }
});

browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tabInfo) => {
    if(tabInfo.url && tabInfo.active === true){
        if(tabInfo.url !== "about:blank" && tabInfo.url !== "about:newtab"){
            setUrlIfDesired("created", tabInfo.url, tabInfo.active);
        }
    }
});

browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    if(activeInfo.tabId !== -1 && activeInfo.tabId !== null){
        browser.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId).then((tabInfo) => {
            setUrlIfDesired("activated", tabInfo.url, tabInfo.active);
        });
    }
});

function setUrlIfDesired(type, url, active){
    console.log(type + ": " + url + " is " + active);
    if(url.indexOf("moz-extension") === -1 && url.indexOf("window.html") === -1){
        urlOfCurrentTab = url;
        console.log("urlOfCurrentTab is now " + urlOfCurrentTab);
        sendMessageToBrowserPopup("getCurrentUrlResult", urlOfCurrentTab);
    }
}

function openMyWindow(tab) {

    browser.windows.create({
        type: "detached_panel",
        url: "window.html",
        titlePreface: "Extension Window",
        width: 350,
        height: 950
    }).then((data) => {
        windowId = data.id;

        // The window needs time to create, it gets 1000 milliseconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            setUrlIfDesired("init", tab.url, true); // initialise the current URL
        }, 1000);
    });
}

// Track whether we need to clear windowId because the window was closed
browser.windows.onRemoved.addListener((removedWindowId) => {
    if(removedWindowId === windowId){
        windowId = -1;
    }
});

/* Add openMyWindow() as a listener to clicks on the browser action. */
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openMyWindow);

function getCurrentUrl(){
    // You would think this would work, but it doesn't. This is because the extension window is the one that is active!
    /*browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then((tabs) => {
        let tab = tabs[0];
        sendMessageToBrowserPopup("getCurrentUrlResult", tab.url);
    });*/

    // So we use the urlOfCurrentTab variable that we kept in memory instead.
    sendMessageToBrowserPopup("getCurrentUrlResult", urlOfCurrentTab);
}

// See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/sendMessage
function sendMessageToBrowserPopup(action, data){
    // Only send messages to the window if it exists
    if(windowId != -1){
        console.log("sending " + data);
        browser.runtime.sendMessage({"action": action, "data": data});
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, we need to edit `window.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension Window</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>  

<h1>My Extension Window</h1>
<p>Active Tab URL: <input id="url" type="text"></p>
<script src="window.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In `window.js` (a new file), we subscribe to the event which was emitted by `background.js`:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "getCurrentUrlResult":
            updateTextbox(message.data);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});

function updateTextbox(urlOfCurrentTab){
    // Update the value in the text box to a new value
    document.getElementById("url").value = urlOfCurrentTab;
}
```

Your manifest.json was good. Don't forget to remove the console.log statements when you understand the code / go to production.

If you have further questions, feel free to ask a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: One more question. If a my web-page "window.html" is loaded from my website, why does not it work? url: "https://www.example.com/extension/window.html"

Comment: Probably because it has no access to window.js, which should run in the browser scope, not in page script scope (otherwise, the browser object is not available). A page script is any script loaded by/to an (external) website.